# Cascade entity reference in a content type

Tags: nodes, entities

I have two content types parts and maintenance.
Parts has 3 fields.

- Oven type
- Oven Part
- Parts price

In maintenance i have a entity reference field with autocomplete that points to parts.
So now when a user types in a part the autocomplete show a list of possible matches.

The problem is that 2 different ovens can have the same parts but the price is different.
So I would like it to be a cascade so that a user can first select the oven and then select the part for this oven.

- select the oventype

  - show the parts that fit this oven

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to try to use [Reference Field Option Limit](https://drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit):

> Example 1:
>
> countries and cities Suppose you want to label articles (or
>   products, or businesses, etc) by both city and country so both can be
>   used for filtering and searching. You could use a hierarchical
>   taxonomy with city terms as children of country terms, but that
>   doesn't make sense when you come to set up Views filters.
>
> With this module, create two separate taxonomies for country and city
>   (or content types, or whatever entity you want to use). Then add a
>   reference field so that each city points to its country: eg, the term
>   'Paris' has a reference to 'France'.
>
> Then when editing an article, selecting 'France' in the country field
>   will cause the city field to update to show only cities in France.

How you denote the different parts based on their price. I dunno. But you can look at this module and if need use it as a starting point to extend or create javascript behaviors or alter sql queries it's using.